# How do I determine whether a SQL Key column was created with compression or not?

Tags: sql-server, reflection, compression, ddl, database-metadata

Consider the following DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_MyKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE=OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY=OFF, DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE)
GO
```

It's a compressed Primary Key. Tada!

What's bothering me is that I don't see any record of that compression in SSMS?

- I don't find it in the Table, Column or Key Properties dialogs, from the context menus of the Object Explorer.
- If I ask SSMS to script => CREATE the key, then it doesn't include that `DATA_COMPRESSION` setting.
  I get:

```
/****** Object:  Index [PK_MyKey]    Script Date: 07/09/2020 11:01:16 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_MyKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

So ... is it possible to tell whether or not an *existing* key (which I didn't create, and who's creation isn't Version Controlled *:sigh:*) was compressed?

Comment: Note that it isn't the key that is compressed, it is the underlying index. One can query the `sys.indexes` catalog view per @Larnu's answer to identify if indexes, including those that support constraints, are compressed and the type of compression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-ver15#metadata) this can be found in the `sys.indexes` and `sys.partitions` objects:

> ### Metadata
>
> The following system views contain information about data compression for clustered indexes:
>
> - [sys.indexes (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-indexes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - The **type** and **type_desc** columns include CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE and NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE.
> - [sys.partitions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - The **data_compression** and **data_compression_desc** columns include COLUMNSTORE and COLUMNSTORE_ARCHIVE.
>
> The procedure [sp_estimate_data_compression_savings (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-estimate-data-compression-savings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can also apply to columnstore indexes.

For the above, specifically, you want to have a look at the column `data_compression` and/or `data_compression_desc`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable_Comp (ID int NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable_Comp
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_MyKey_C] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE=OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY=OFF, DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable_NoComp (ID int NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable_NoComp
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_MyKey_NC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE=OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY=OFF);

GO

SELECT i.[name], p.[data_compression], p.data_compression_desc
FROM sys.indexes i
     JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE i.[name] IN ('PK_MyKey_C','PK_MyKey_NC');

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable_Comp;
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable_NoComp
```

For the above 2 tables, this returns the following:

```
name        | data_compression | data_compression_desc
------------|------------------|----------------------
PK_MyKey_C  | 2                | PAGE
PK_MyKey_NC | 0                | NONE
```